# Алгоритм выполнения по условию

Tags: php, mysql

Ребята помогите битый час не могу до курить одну штуку.
В общем в БД есть поле в которое через jq пост запрос обновляются данные тип поля **int(11)**.

На страницу вывожу переменную с значением из поля (бд).
Для примера это будет так:

my_sum = '22';

И есть кнопки которые отправляют разные суммы чисел для изменения этого поля (бд).

Которые добавляются так:

```
update `myTable` set summ=summ+".$_GET['my_sum']." where id='".$id."'
```

И есть кнопки которые отнимают число 100 и 50.

```
update `myTable` set summ=summ-".$_GET['my_sum']." where id='".$id."'
```

Так вот как составить алгоритм условие дабы если значение переменной my_sum равно 22 отнимало разницу между 22 и 100 или 50.
Но так же если my_sum равен 0 то отравлять 0 а, не 100 или 50.

Ибо если my_sum равен 22 и нажать на отнять 100 в бд в поле заносится -78.

Помогите решить заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно отнять от `summ`, но так, чтобы `summ` не оказалось меньше нуля? СУБД MySQL?

Comment: Спасибо вам за быструю реакцию) Да вы правы мне нужно что бы в бд не заносилось значение меньше нуля. субд MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MySQL есть функция `GREATEST()` которая возвращает максимальный аргумент из переданных. Вот вам и нужно использовать эту функцию

```
update `myTable` set
  summ = GREATEST(summ - " . $_GET['my_sum'] . ", 0)
where
  id = '".$id."'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "update `myTable`  
set `summ`= IF((summ-".$_GET['my_sum']) < 0, 0, summ-".$_GET['my_sum'].")  
where id='$id'";
```

Надо проверять что тебе через GET подсунули.